# Android-NDK build system (building hello-gl2)

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, sample, toolchain

I downloaded and installed Android-NDK on my Archlinux, using [this package](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=27656).

Got no issues building (and running) the sample `hello-jni` following the guide on [this page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html), but if I try to do the same with `hello-gl2` I get some errors; it looks like it cannot find some header files:

```
$ ../../ndk-build 
/usr/bin/make -f /opt/android-ndk/build/core/build-local.mk
Compile++ thumb  : gl2jni <= gl_code.cpp
/opt/android-ndk/samples/hello-gl2/jni/gl_code.cpp:22:23: error: GLES2/gl2.h: No such file or directory
/opt/android-ndk/samples/hello-gl2/jni/gl_code.cpp:23:26: error: GLES2/gl2ext.h: No such file or directory
--- SNIP ---
```

`GLES2/gl2.h` and `GLES2/gl2ext.h` are however present in `$(NDK)/platforms/android-4/arch-arm/usr/include/`, and it looks like`$(NDK)/build/core/setup-toolchain.mk` should set such include path.

Has anybody encountered the same issue? How can I compile this sample?
And then, are there other options to easily build Android-NDK applications? This build system seems quite complicated to me, and I'd prefer using cmake to build my applications.

Comment: I am having the same problem. ndk-build gives the same errors. I am on a Mac though. Any tips?

Answer (score 6):

make sure that APP_ABI and APP_PLATFORM is defined in your Application.mk and your APP_PLATFORM should be higher than android-5... check: [gl.h & glext.h not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793910/gl-h-glext-h-not-found)

for example, in Application.mk define:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi #armeabi-v7a
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

Comment: Eclipse -> Android Studio migration was missing this. Now NDK builds work! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was missing the file *default.properties* with such content:

```
target=android-5
```

Put this file into the root project directory. It may help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a higher SDK. Level 5 is the minimum to build OpenGL ES 2 code.

Comment: I've got installed android-sdk r08-2 and android-ndk r5-1. Do I need to specify which version to use to `ndk-buidl`?

Comment: Your installs are fine. Adjust the hello-jni project from inside eclipse.

Comment: `hello-jni` compiles and runs fine. Problem is with `hello-gl2`, which doesn't compile when I run `ndk-build`...

Comment: I understand that. When I had the same problem, all I needed to do was adjust the API level of my project.