# gl.h & glext.h not found

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk, java-native-interface

While trying to execute a program based on C++ in android via NDK platform, the compilation is giving error that 'gl.h' and 'glext.h' header files are not found, as I have included both of them in my C++ code.
    M using android-ndk-r8 and compiling it with Cygwin.

```
here s my code:   
**ANDROID.MK**

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := NDK1
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp) 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%) 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

---
**APPLICATION.MK**

APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a 
APP_PLATFORM := android-3

---
**Viewer.cpp**

#include <iostream>

#import "OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h"
#import "OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h"

//#import <GLKit/GLKEffects.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKMath.h>

#include "Viewer.h"

void Viewer::render() {
    glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArrayOES( _vertexArray[0]);

    // Render the object with GLKit


    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

    /////////
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray[1]);

    // Render the object with GLKit
    //[self.effect prepareToDraw];

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
}

void Viewer::initialize() {
    sceneObj.constructDemoScene();

    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    ///////////////////////////////////
    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray[0]);
    glBindVertexArrayOES( _vertexArray[0]);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer[0]);
    H3DModel * model = sceneObj.get3DModel(0);
    float * vertices = model->vertexBuffObj.getVertices();
    for (int c = 0; c < 216; c++)
        printf("%f\t", vertices[c]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 216 * 4, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray( EVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(EVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24,
            (void*) offsetof(Vertex, position));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( EVertexAttribNormal);
    glVertexAttribPointer(EVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24,
            (void*) offsetof(Vertex, normal));

    ///////////////////////////////////

    glGenVertexArraysOES(2, &_vertexArray[1]);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray[1]);

    glGenBuffers(2, &_vertexBuffer[1]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer[1]);
    H3DModel * model1 = sceneObj.get3DModel(1);
    float * vertices1 = model1->vertexBuffObj.getVertices();
    for (int c = 0; c < 216; c++)
        printf("%f\t", vertices[c]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 216 * 4, vertices1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(EVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(EVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24,
            (void*) offsetof(Vertex, position));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(EVertexAttribNormal);
    glVertexAttribPointer(EVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24,
            (void*) offsetof(Vertex, normal));

    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
}

void Viewer::unInitialize() {
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer[0]);
    glDeleteBuffers(2, &_vertexBuffer[1]);
    glDeleteVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray[0]);
    glDeleteVertexArraysOES(2, &_vertexArray[1]);

    if (_program) {
        glDeleteProgram( _program);
        _program = 0;
    }
}

GLKMatrix4 Viewer::update() {
    GLKMatrix4 baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f,
            -4.0f);
    baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(baseModelViewMatrix, _rotation,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Compute the model view matrix for the object rendered with GLKit
    //GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.5f);
    //modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, _rotation, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    //modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(baseModelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

    //self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = baseModelViewMatrix;

    /*// Compute the model view matrix for the object rendered with ES2
     modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.5f);
     modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, _rotation, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
     modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(baseModelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

     _normalMatrix = GLKMatrix3InvertAndTranspose(GLKMatrix4GetMatrix3(modelViewMatrix), NULL);

     _modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix);*/

    _rotation += 0.04f;
    return baseModelViewMatrix;
}
```

Thanks in advance..i want to know how to use OPENGL ES in android ndk !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite sure, but I believe if you looking into the sample code provided by google ndk, it could be a great help.

the sample code located at

```
    android-ndk-r7b\samples\hello-gl2\jni\gl_code.cpp
```

If compare the Android.mk, you will find your

```
    LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -lGLESv2
```

is missing. The Android.mk provided by Google is looks like below:

```
    LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE    := libgl2jni
    LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := gl_code.cpp
    LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -lGLESv2

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and also, in the cpp source code, android is using :

```
    #include <GLES2/gl2.h>
    #include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>
```

Comment: thanks...but I tried adding the LOCAL_LDLIBS also, but still it shows that the GLES header files are missing, I dont know how to add/locate dese files.. :(

Comment: are you using #import or #include?

Comment: as mentioned above...m using #import. Also tried using #include but still d errors r dere !!

Comment: #include <GLES2/gl2.h> & #include <GLES2/gl2ext.h> is working but #include <GLKit/GLKMath.h> is stil giving problem, i think its path also needs to be modified.

Comment: #include <GLKit/GLKMath.h> - this guy from iOS :) remove it

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `#import` in C/C++. Also you need to increase `APP_PLATFORM` level. OpenGL ES 1 is available only stating from `android-4` and OpenGL ES 2 is available from `android-5`. It's all in the documentation: `docs/STABLE-APIS.html` file.

Comment: Yes i have increased dat as u said & changed al my imports to include, finaly my APPLICATION.MK is:                                 APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a 

APP_PLATFORM := android-8 

APP_STL := stlport_static ...still #include <GLKit/GLKMath.h> is giving error as GLKMatrix is not found...!!

Comment: There is no such thing as GLKit on Android. That's iOS specific.

Comment: ok...so how to include GLKMath.h as GLMatrix is not being found during compilation, or any other header file is needed for dat ?

Comment: GLKMath is part of GLKit. GLKit is available only for iOS. If you want your code to be cross-platform then don't use platform specific libraries/includes. Use cross-platform libraries. For math you can use cml-dev or glm.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were trying to build in the jni directory. Try again in the root directory of the Android project.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know if this issue is still common. I just had this issue and found one solution. It turned out the file "Application.mk" was needed in the "jni" directory.

This is my "Application.mk":

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
```

I think "APP_PLATFORM := android-14" informed Android of using Opengl ES. In fact, "APP_PLATFORM := android-5" is the minimum requirement for OpenGL 2.x.